# What's the best practice to create a script which initiate a folder structure

Tags: bash, meteor

I'm trying to evolve with Meteor and I would to delegate the boilerplate task of project structure creation to a script (a kind of Angularjs-seed project).

I want to have some advises/pointers about an efficient way(s) to structure the script to create the project structure and be able to maintain the script in order to customize easily.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to go might be to git clone SachaG's void template (an empty meteor project just for the structure):

```
git clone https://github.com/SachaG/Void.git
```

So with that you get the directory structure, a blank app and a router. All just needs to be filled in.

Comment: Thanks there's some modifications to do before using it correctly as Meteor is a very active project and it changes hour after hour. thanks !

Comment: @Abderrazakk if you found any please try send them as PRs so its kept up to date.